# how to align a set of long equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm trying to align a long equation like in the picture below

[image]

here is the code i used and my output

```
\[ 
\begin{split}
& 
\Biggl[\biggl(1-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr) \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s}\smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}\Biggr)^{-\frac{\sst 1}{\sst 1+p^{z}_{t+s}}}
\\
&\quad-\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)\biggl(-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr) {\biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s}\smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}}\Biggr)^{-1} \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}\Biggr)^{-\frac{\sst 1}{\sst 1+p^{z}_{t+s}}} \biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}\Biggr)\biggr]Y_{t+s\textbar{t}}
\end{split}
\]
```

my output

[image]

Comment: please fix your example so it is a complete document (then you can check it does not generate errors such as) `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sst `

Comment: Please write `\mid t` instead of `\textbar{t}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that splits the long factor across three rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsmath}        % for "split" environment
\newcommand\1{\vphantom{1}} % a strut with the height of "1"
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{split}
   \Biggl[
   &\biggl(1-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr) 
   \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\mid t}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}_{\1}^{1-\theta} P^{}_{t-1+s}}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}} \\
   &-\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j) \biggl(-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr) 
   \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\mid t}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}_{\1}^{1-\theta} P^{}_{t-1+s}}\biggr)^{\!-1} \\
   &\qquad\times
   \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\mid t}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}_{\1}^{1-\theta} P^{}_{t-1+s}}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}} 
   \biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}_{\1}^{1-\theta} P^{}_{t-1+s}}\biggr)
   \Biggr] Y_{t+s\mid t} 
   = \dots
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite your equation, for example in the following form:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[(1-A)\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)^{-A} - 
    \mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j) 
    (-A)
    \left(\frac{B}{C}\right)^{-1}
    \left(\frac{B}{C}\right)^{-A}
    \left(\frac{1}{C}\right)^{-1}
\right]Y_{t+s|t} =
\]
where are:
    \begin{align*}
A & = \frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}       \\
B & = P^{\circ}_{t+s|t}(j) \\
C & = \Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s}\overline{\Pi}^{1-\theta}_{} P_{t-1+s}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

To my opinion the equation is more clear and easier to read.

**Edit:**
in the first version of the answer was misplaced *A*, now is also simplified definition of *C*.