# Align long equations using a macro

Tags: equations, subcaption, split

How do I align this equation like in the picture below?

[image]

Here is the code I used and my output:

```
\[
  \begin{split}
    \Biggl\{ \biggl( {1 - \frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t + s}}} \biggr)
    P^{\circ}^{X}_{t + s\textbar{t}} (i)^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}}} \Biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s}
      \bar{\Pi}^{1 - \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr)^{-\frac{1}{1
        + \rho_{f, t + s}}} - \\%
    \frac{S^{-1}_{t + s}\mathcal{MC}_{x, t +
        s}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1 -
        \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \left( -\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}} \right) \Biggl[ \frac{P^{\circ}^{X}_{t +
        s\textbar{t}}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1
        - \theta_{x}}P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr]^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f,
          t + s}} - 1} \Biggr\} X_{t + s\textbar{t}}
  \end{split}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than the back tick notation, or pre code HTML, try highlighting your code and hitting ctrl + k (or the code sample button, which is the one that looks like {}), this adds four spaces at the start of each line and produces a nicely formatted code block with syntax highlighting and everything. I've added a lot of whitespace to your source code and hard-wrapped it, this is mainly so it fits nicely into the question box so people don't have to scroll left and right to read it all

Comment: this seems to be duplicate of your previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342698/how-to-align-a-set-of-long-equations

Comment: i have tried the previous suggestions however, i couldn't get this aligned form with bigger bounderies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrote this equation into form:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{multlined}[b][0.7\textwidth]
\left\{\left(1 - A\right) P^{\circ X}_{t + s | t} (i)^{-A}
    \left(\frac{1}{B}\right)^{-A} \right.\\
\left. - \frac{S^{-1}_{t + s}\mathcal{MC}_{x, t + s}(i)}{B} \left(-A\right) 
    \left[ \frac{P^{\circ X}_{t + s | t}(i)}{B} \right]^{-A - 1}
\right\} X_{t + s | t} = ?% not specified
  \end{multlined}
\]
where are:
    \[
A = \frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t + s}}   
    \quad\text{and}\quad
B = \Pi^{\theta_x}_{x,t-1+s}\bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta_x}_{} P^{X}_{t-1+s}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

using the `gathered` environment from `mathtools`, and moving the large braces and what follows *outside* that environment yields the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{
  \begin{gathered}
   \biggl( {1 - \frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t + s}}} \biggr)
    P^{\circ X}_{t + s | t} (i)^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}}} \Biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s}
      \bar{\Pi}^{1 - \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr)^{-\frac{1}{1
        + \rho_{f, t + s}}} - \\%
    \frac{S^{-1}_{t + s}\mathcal{MC}_{x, t +
        s}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1 -
        \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \left( -\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}} \right) \Biggl[ \frac{P^{\circ X}_{t +
        s | t}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1
        - \theta_{x}}P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr]^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f,
          t + s}} - 1}
  \end{gathered}
  \right\} X_{t + s | t}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lrcases` environment (`cases` with left and right braces, following a code from @Gonzalo Medina) and `nccmath` to have medium-sized fractions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\makeatletter
\newcases{dlrcases}{\quad}{%
$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\newcases{lrcases}{\quad}{%
$\m@th{##}$\hfil}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{lrcases} \Bigl( {1 - \mfrac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t + s}}}\Bigr)
    P^{ ∘ X}_{t + s\textbar{t}} (i)^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
      s}}} \Bigl( \mfrac{1}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s}
    \bar{Π}^{1 - \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Bigr)^{-\frac{1}{1
      + \rho_{f, t + s}}} - \\%
    \mfrac{S⁻¹_{t + s}\mathcal{MC}_{x, t +
      s}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{Π}^{1 -
      \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Bigl( -\mfrac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
      s}} \Bigr) \biggl[ \mfrac{P^{ ∘ X}_{t +
        s\textbar{t}}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{Π}^{1
      - \theta_{x}}P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \biggr]^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f,
        t + s}} - 1} \end{lrcases} X_{t + s\textbar{t}}
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a stack (note I also had to change `^{\circ}^{X}` into `^{\circ X}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{
\ensurestackMath{\stackanchor[10pt]{
    \biggl( {1 - \frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t + s}}} \biggr)
    P^{\circ X}_{t + s\textbar{t}} (i)^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}}} \Biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s}
      \bar{\Pi}^{1 - \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr)^{-\frac{1}{1
        + \rho_{f, t + s}}} - 
}{
    \frac{S^{-1}_{t + s}\mathcal{MC}_{x, t +
        s}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1 -
        \theta_{x}} P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \left( -\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f, t +
          s}} \right) \Biggl[ \frac{P^{\circ X}_{t +
        s\textbar{t}}(i)}{\Pi^{\theta_{x}}_{x, t - 1 + s} \bar{\Pi}^{1
        - \theta_{x}}P^X_{t - 1 + s}} \Biggr]^{-\frac{1}{1 + \rho_{f,
          t + s}} - 1}
}}
\right\} X_{t + s\textbar{t}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Substituting `\documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}` as cited by the OP in a comment, still compiles OK.  Note. am using `stackengine 2016/10/04 v4.00`:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, however i don't understand why your code shows me '  fatal error occured' , i'm using the \documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}

Comment: @haithem I can compile successfully with that setting.  Make sure you have the latest version of the `stackengine` package: `stackengine 2016/10/04 v4.00` found at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Comment: thanks it works now i had to update my miktex using package manager..